# How to change JAXB Marshaller line separator?

Tags: java, file-io, jaxb, marshalling

What property is used to change the Marshaller (`javax.xml.bind.Marshaller`) line separator (carriage return, new line, line break)?

I believe the marshaller is using the systems's line separator.

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

However a different escape sequence is needed (i.e. `\r\n` needs to be changed to `\n` or vice versa).

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

marshaller.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no a property that you can customize. Most [implementations](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/runtime/output/IndentingUTF8XmlOutput.java#IndentingUTF8XmlOutput.printIndent%28%29) send directly to the buffer the line separator:

```
write('\n');
```

However, you can replace the result.

```
Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(1024); // 2 KB
marshaller.marshal(obj, writer);

String str = writer.toString();
str = str.replaceAll("\r?\n", "\r\n");  // only convert if necessary
```

To avoid any effect on the performance, you must set the approximate size (e.g. `1024 -> 2 KB`) in the constructor for [`java.io.StringWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html).

Comment: Isn't this a little dangerous? If the implementation ever changes, then this will produce "\r\n\n".

Comment: Hmm... You are right! In tha case, `str = str.replaceAll("\r?\n", "\r\n");`